# Magento - Implementing a custom product import function

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I have a Magento 1.6 website which will have to import products from several CSV files provided by the suppliers. I saw that there's an import function, but it won't be flexible enough for what I have to do.

To be specific, I have to tasks to perform:

- Choosing a supplier for a product, when it's sold by multiple
  suppliers.
- Re-map product categories.

Here are the details of the above.

**Choosing a supplier**
Suppliers will provide their product lists, and different lists may contain the same products. The import function will have to compare the products to be imported and, following some logic, "assign" each product to one or the other supplier.

**Example**: product *XYZ* is sold by supplier **A**, supplier **B** and supplier **C**. **A** sells it cheaper, **B** is the second cheapest, **C** is the dearest. However, **A** doesn't have it in stock, **B** has a few and **C** has plenty. Product should then be "assigned" to **B**, and its details extracted from such list.

The effect of such assignment should be that, when our Customers will place an order, it will be automatically translated into multiple orders to our suppliers (I still have to find out how, though).

**Re-mapping product categories**
When we receive the product lists from the suppliers, they are associated to supplier's categories. For example, a flat screen TV might be in "Home Electronics" category in one supplier's list, and in "Electronics" in another list. We have therefore created a "map", which specifies, for each supplier category, the destination category in our system.
What I need to do is going through the imported products and re-assigning them to the proper category.

The logic of both tasks is quite easy, and I'd be able to implement it without any issue, if it wasn't for the fact that I'm completely new to Magento. What would be the best approach to tackle them, in such case? Should I implement a custom module? In case, what would be the best place to start?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to make new import profile for this just create new import profile,put your csv file in var/import folder and make new php file for doing this, see how magento default import works then put your php file in app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Adapter/
and make some xml changes in import profile you have created and you are done

Comment: Thanks. The issue is that I have more than one CSV file, with different structures and I have to process them at the same time. In practice I would have to do a "pre-import", then sort out the products I want to take and, finally, map their categories. Can this be done with an import profile?

Comment: yes this can be done with one import profile, run your main csv file and in the code read your other csv file magento process your main csv file but in your code you can process your csv file too.

Comment: Understood. I'll have a look at the profiles, it seems easier than I thought. Thanks.